# Python mongoengine cant connect remote server

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

I've been using mongoengine to connect my remote mongo server

while the same code result in different condotions, the code

```
connect('COLLECTION_NAME', host='PUBLIC_IP', port=PORT)
```

when I type this at python shell, the return value will be

```
MongoClient(host=['128.199.160.47:27017']
```

which is correct

while when I use the same code at Django and execute it, the return value become

```
MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017']
```

no matter how I try, it cannot connect to the remote server

could anybody help??

Answer (score 0):

'128.199.160.47:27017' - it's full address, where **128.199.160.47 is host** and **27017 is port**. Host is string, port is integer.

Use like:

```
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
```

Comment: I've tried this before, it doesn'work
I find the solution, just need to add alias option when using connect

Comment: @wtichen Try do it with localhost

Comment: I know it's better to use localhost, I was just trying, anyway, thx

Comment: I know MongoClient can complete this, I just dont figure it out why it doesn't work when using MongoEngine, which based on MongoClient, so I traced the source code and finf add alias is a way to do this